# RGB adjustment for monitor RGB difference

Tags: rgb

Ok so, I have a color wife want to paint a room that we found on google on home computer.
The color is RGB-(113, 121, 126) the color does not match phone RGB value because monitor RGB value is not same as phone.
Monitor values are RGB-(71, 76, 100) how do I combine the two in order to find a true RGB value?

Answer (score 3):

**You don't.**

Neither is from a colour-managed system. In fact those numbers are *so* far apart from each other no-one would know whether you actually wanted a greenish grey or a slate blue.

Without a managed colour system you will simply *never* get the colour you think you are getting. Also, though you *can* buy paint from an RGB specification, only specialist manufacturers will sell you it this way. Most want you to go to a store & look at a physical swatch. That way you can't later claim the colour was "wrong".

This is what your two sets of numbers look like on my screen, which *is* colour-managed… though, of course I cannot know what your screen will show you.

[image]

Even though I know my display will show the 'correct' colour, I *still* wouldn't use it to choose paint - because you're then getting into another difficulty… how a colour created by light translates to a colour created by pigment.

Another tip - when you get to the paint store & have narrowed down something like the colour you *actually* want, check it under the lights by the swatches [which will hopefully be some sort of 'accurate' light] then also check under the regular store lights away from the paint section, then also check outdoors. The quality of the light falling on the swatches can significantly affect your colour perception.

<sup>BTW, I'm aware this is off-topic, but I thought it deserved a "Don't do that, you'll regret it" before anyone actually went off to buy random-coloured paint.</sup>

Comment: re: your bottom note: it definitely _feels_ off-topic, but your answer is exactly what I would expect when people ask about comparing printed photos vs. on-screen photos. So... yeah. Great answer! =)

Comment: @scottbb - Thanks, yeah, it didn't seem the time to be going into profiling & hardware calibration [would cost more than the paint anyway ;)